# cURL works but none of the rest clients with Go sebserver

Tags: post, curl, go, httpserver, dhclient

Having a simple GO WebServer which accepts an image as part of POST request.

Code snippet - Request is mapped to this function

```
 func UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
        successResponse := models.HTTPResponse {
            FileURL:"http://testing.com",
        }
        WrapResponse(w, successResponse, http.StatusOK)
    }
```

Response writer function

```
func WrapResponse(writer http.ResponseWriter, content interface{}, status int) {    
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    writer.WriteHeader(status)
    // Content is a struct Response { fileURL string }  
    responseJson, err := json.Marshal(content)  
    CheckError(err, "Error wrapping response")  
    writer.Write(responseJson) 
    }

    func CheckError(err error, msg string) {    
    if err != nil {         
    panic(fmt.Sprintf("%s : %s", msg, err))     
    } 
    }
```

When i hit the URL using cURL as below the response is 200 OK (as expected)

> curl -X POST -d@ "Screen Shot 2015-11-15 at 6.09.58 pm.png"
>   http://localhost:8000/image/agent123/property --header "Content-Type:image/png"
>   --header "X-User-Agent:agent-php"  response -->{"fileURL":"http://testing.com"}%

Entire cURL request & response 
[image: Verbose]

But when i try the same from DHC rest client, have also tried with advanced rest client getting no response.

[image: Same request via DHC]

Edit 1: Request does reach the server when fired from rest clients

Comment: What is the problem? Where is your code?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Please let me know what else u need. I thought there is some extra header added by rest clients since cURL worked. I don't think anything wrong with the code that is why didn't paste the code.

Comment: Try running curl as verbose with --verbose to see exactly waht it's sending.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe you're doing what you think you are.

```
curl -X POST -d "Screen Shot 2015-11-15 at 6.09.58 pm.png" http://localhost:8000/image/agent123/property --header "Content-Type:image/png" --header "X-User-Agent:agent-php"
```

Will not send the file "Screen Shot 2015-11-15 at 6.09.58 pm.png", it's gonig to send the literal text as the body. You probably want "-d @'Screen Shot 2015-11-15 at 6.09.58 pm.png'".

Which then your "good" result is not exactly good, so you have to figure out what the bug is at the receiving end on the server. As the GUI client you're using is probably sending the file, whereas cURL is not. And your backend seems to accept text, not files.

Comment: curl -X POST -d@"Screen Shot 2015-11-15 at 6.09.58 pm.png" http://localhost:8000/image/agentId/property --header "Content-Type:image/png" --header "X-User-Agent:agent-php"
{"fileURL":"http://testing.com"}%

Comment: @Itachi I'm still not convinced it's doing what you think it's doing, nonetheless you have to provide the route/receiving code if you want debugging help.

Comment: Have added the request processing function. Are the information enough ?